# Copying a file inside an S3 bucket (ruby)

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buckets

I'm using gem aws-sdk-ruby and I want to copy a file /images/image_a.png to /profile.png
all resides inside the same bucket.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extracted from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingRuby.html), you'll have to use the `copy_to`. For instance:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new

# Upload a file and set server-side encryption.
bucket1 = s3.buckets[source_bucket]
bucket2 = s3.buckets[target_bucket]
obj1 = bucket1.objects[source_key]
obj2 = bucket2.objects[target_key]

obj1.copy_to(obj2)
```

Comment: If the target is in the same bucket, you can simply do: s3.buckets['bucket-name'].objects['source'].copy_to('target')

Answer (score 3):

to do this with aws-sdk-v2 you can do the following:

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new('my_aws_bucket')
bucket.object("new_photo_uploads/logos/my_new_copied_photo.png")
aws_response = object.copy_from(bucket.object("my_original_photo.png"))
```